# Mistakenly Transferred Compressed NFT to another Compressed NFT (instread of wallet)

Tags: nft, cnft

On Helium, a physical hotspot device has a ECC for signing transactions. It's represented on the Helium L2 as a Compressed NFT.

I purchased a used hostspot and the seller accidentally transferred it to one of my other hotspot (compressed NFT) addresses, instead of my wallet.

The incoming Hotspot/Compressed NFT has left his wallet.

I have been told that if I sign a transaction via the Hotspot, I can issue another transfer request, this time to the correct wallet address.

I have SSH to the hotspot and am able to transact on the ECC e.g `execute provision, provision_onboard, and onboarding operations`. [Documentation](https://docs.helium.com/hotspot-makers/become-a-maker/security-requirements/).

How can I construct a transfer transaction or provisioning transaction to recover this compressed NFT into my Helium/Solana wallet?

Any other info would be appreciated. Even pure Solana advice/approaches. I appreciate some of this is happening at different API/layers and the solution may be prior to the blockchain itself.

Edit: A secondary question is... is a Compressed NFT assigned to a Compressed NFT I own, truly in my wallet and in my control... or is it in oblivion?

Edit2: I have been able to construct a transfer request and it failed. It seems the cNFT has been assigned a new owner (that is not my other hotspot cNFT) is that expected?

Comment: Also it would be good if someone with more reputation than me add a Helium tag since Helium are now a big user of Solana :)

Comment: Reopened question

Comment: Okay thanks for deleting my old comment weirdo
Could you please share the code constructed to check if it would work in my case
my main issue is the cross chain transit :/

Comment: Aint nobody gonna help you @DavidMatar if you talk like that.

Comment: And for the record I didn't delete anything.